# Evaluating a Fermi gas problem for a SO(2N+1) matrix integral

Tags: integration, random-matrices, theta-functions, elliptic-functions

I have the following multiple integral derived from a random matrix calculation I wish to evaluate

$$\int_0^{\pi} dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_n \rho(x_1,x_2)\cdots \rho(x_n,x_1)$$

where the $\rho$ functions are given by

$$ \rho(x,x') = \text{Sn}^2\bigg(\theta_3^2(0,q) \frac{x}{2}\bigg)\text{Sn}\bigg(\theta_3^2(0,q)\frac{(x+x')}{2}\bigg)\text{Sn}\bigg(\theta_3^2(0,q)\frac{(x-x')}{2}\bigg) $$

and the $Sn$ functions are Jacobi Elliptic functions with modulus $k=\theta_2^2(0,q)/\theta_3^2(0,q)$.

The $\rho$ functions are even in their respective arguments and so we can extend the integral to the range $[0,2\pi)$ by introducing a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ for each integration.

The Fourier representation of the elliptic functions is given by

$$ \text{sn}\bigg(\theta_3^2 \frac{\alpha}{2}\bigg) = \frac{2i}{\theta_2^2}\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{i(n-\frac{1}{2})\alpha}}{q^{n-\frac{1}{2}}-q^{-(n-\frac{1}{2})}} $$

and we can appeal to orthogonality of the complex exponentials over the given range to give a Kronecker delta for each integral.

Ignoring overall multiplicative factors for the moment, and using the notation
$$ g_{a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i} = \frac{1}{q^{a_i-\frac{1}{2}}-q^{-(a_i-\frac{1}{2})}}\frac{1}{q^{b_i-\frac{1}{2}}-q^{-(b_i-\frac{1}{2})}}\frac{1}{q^{c_i-\frac{1}{2}}-q^{-(c_i-\frac{1}{2})}}\frac{1}{q^{d_i-\frac{1}{2}}-q^{-(d_i-\frac{1}{2})}}$$

I am then left with the following

$$\sum_{\{a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1\}\cdots\{a_n,b_n,c_n,d_n\}} g_{a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1}\cdots g_{a_n,b_n,c_n,d_n} \delta_{a_1+b_1+c_1+d_1,c_n-d_n+2}\cdots \delta_{a_n+b_n+c_n+d_n,c_{n-1}-d_{n-1}+2}$$

The sum over $n$ of the integers (such as the $\{a_i\}$) can now be evaluated.

Unfortunately I am left with $3n$ summations, and any way of writing this in terms of known functions or simplifying this object so that there are fewer summation variables seems opaque to me.

Any help with simplifying this expression (for example, in terms of theta functions) would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

I have managed to compute the summation over the $a_i$ and $b_i$ indices and am left with the following:

$$ \frac{1}{q^n}\sum_{(c_1,d_1)\cdots(c_n,d_n)} \frac{q^{2c_1}}{(1-q^{2c_1-1})(1-q^{2d_1 -1})} f(c_n,d_n,c_1,d_1) \cdots  \frac{q^{2c_n}}{(1-q^{2c_n-1})(1-q^{2d_n -1})} f(c_{n-1},d_{n-1},c_n,d_n)$$

where f(a,b,c,d) is given by

$$ \frac{1+a-b-(c+d)}{1-q^{2(1+a-b-(c+d))}}, \quad  1+a-b-(c+d)\neq 1$$
and

$$ A = -\frac{1}{4} \frac{\theta''_4(0)}{\theta_4(0)}, \quad 1+a-b-(c+d)=0 $$

I'm hoping that a change of variables or brute forcing computing some of the intermediate summations may be able to simplify this further.